# Mips Syscall 5 Invalid Integer Input Error

Tags: mips

I am new to Mips. While using syscall 5, I saw that I cannot get integers bigger than 2,147,483,647. I get the error below:

*Runtime exception at 0x00400004: invalid integer input (syscall 5)*

**The syscall I use to get integers**

```
li $v0, 5
syscall
```

Comment: That's the upper limit (`0x7FFFFFFF`). I'm not sure what your question is(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my knowledge, MIPS does not support integers greater than 32 bit. For high-level languages, the compiler translates `long long int` to work using `32 bit registers` in assembly language.

Answer (score -1):

You need to move the value in $v0  to a registor.
You should use this:

```
 li $v0 , 5
 syscall
 move $t1 , $v0
```